# JSF 2.0 - Ajax submit validation on inputs

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a form that needs to be submitted with ajax. I am trying to get the validation to work but it wont work when I use ajax. When I take the ajax out and submit the form with an empty testinput it properly triggers he validation and does not submit the form. How can I do this with an ajax call. My form is below.

```
<h:form>
  <f:ajax>
   <h:panelGrid columns="3">
       <h:outputLable for=test" value="testinput:" />
       <h:inputText id=test" required="true" label="testinput" />
       <h:message for="test" id="testError"/>
   </h:panelGrid>

   <h:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{testBean.doSomething}" />
  </f:ajax>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 5):

The `<f:ajax>` by default doesn't re-render the form, so you won't see anything. Replace `<f:ajax>` by `<f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />`.

Comment: This is just a question because ajax wont always do what I want it to. Shouldn't he put <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"> inside the command button so that it triggers when an ActionEvent occurs or would his code do the same?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try something like this:

```
<h:form id="yourFormId">
  <!-- form content -->

  <h:commandButton value="Submit">
    <f:ajax execute="yourFormId" listener="#{testBean.doSomething}"/>
  </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```